# Is it possible to post images and videos to instagram using api in android without redirecting to app

Tags: android, video, upload, instagram, photo

I want to post photos and videos to Instagram from an android app using API,there is no proper documentation or example regarding this how can I achieve it any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook API's publishing is not possible. But you can read data from users Instagram Profile. But this api features need contract signing and business verification. Please check in Facebook Developer.

[image]

Comment: is facebook graph Api and instagram api are same to post

Comment: I think they are different! But see, you can't post in Instagram. All apis allow read capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Ok so that means we cant upload or post photos or video to Instagram using third-party apps or any API's right. Any alternate if you have, It will be helpful for me.

Comment: even, I am looking for the same.

Comment: maybe asking user name and the password of instagram and on backend post it with selenium. I dont think users will do it but thats the only way I can think of.